# Unauthorized Access with Paypal REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Everything works fine in a development/localhost environment.

When deploying to heroku, using sandbox/test credentials on a new app, and creating a new payment I am getting

```
A PayPal::SDK::Core::Exceptions::UnauthorizedAccess occurred in orders#create:

  Failed.  Response code = 401.  Response message = Unauthorized.
```

Again, everything thing works in a development environment

Should I permit any specific domains (like in Facebook integration)?

Comment: Are you sure you are not running against PayPals production servers? See point 3 at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/

Comment: Perhaps you're not setting your credentials correctly for different environments? Another issue could be you're using `ENV` variables to send to the `PayPal` API, and these will change with your environment

Comment: did you ever work out your issue?  I am having similar results trying to access payments.

Comment: My conclusion was a delay in accepted new credentials, since the issue resolved itself after a lot of swearing and anger

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a Rails application on a public server, there is quite a chance that the Rails environment is set to "production".

If you further use the `config/initializers/paypal.rb` and `config/paypal.yml` generated by the Paypal API SDK's standard generator, then:

- the initializer [loads configuration for the current Rails environment](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/blob/d677b5e55107de05a637af75cb323def0ca27721/lib/generators/paypal/sdk/templates/paypal.rb#L1), which is "production"
- and in the production configuration [one important line](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/blob/d677b5e55107de05a637af75cb323def0ca27721/lib/generators/paypal/sdk/templates/paypal.yml#L29) presumes that you want to run on the live API

So most probably you are attempting to communicate with the live API without knowing it. Changing the line to `mode: sandbox` should make you happy.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I called Paypal. It was a config problem in my account.
To resolve I went to https://developer.paypal.com, logged in, Then clicked on **Dashboard** Then on **my account** (left) The **Direct credit cards** has a grey x next to it so you have to click the link next to it that reads **Enable live credentials** Once you do this you have to answer some verification questions then they approve your account then your live and the unauthorized error goes away.